# Returning earliest ID from table including other rows

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

Given this data:

```
itemID  note        color   updateddate description
AA123   not unique  blue    2014-01-01  duplicate 1
AB789   unique      green   2013-11-20  unique 1
AA123   not unique  pink    2012-01-01  duplicate 2
CC123   unique      blue    2014-12-11  unique 2
CA123   unique      red     2014-08-06  unique 3
CB333   unique      red     2014-03-03  unique 4
CX123   unique      brown   2014-09-01  unique 5
XX111   not unique  red     2014-07-07  duplicate 3
XX111   not unique  yellow  2014-06-06  duplicate 4
XX111   not unique  purple  2014-05-05  duplicate 5
```

How can i select from it, returning all rows fully, but where there are Id's that are duplicate i only want to return the earliest one by its updateddate? In MySQL i understand this is fairly easy to do, but in MSSQL i cant fathom it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with self join and a CTE:

```
WITH MinDates_CTE (itemD, MinDate) AS
(
    SELECT itemID,
           MIN(updatdate) AS MinDate
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY itemID
)

SELECT MyTable.*
FROM MyTable
JOIN MinDates_CTE 
    ON MinDates_CTE.itemID = MyTable.itemID
    AND MinDates_CTE.MinDate = MyTable.updatedate
```

Alternatively you can use a window function:

```
SELECT itemID, note, color, updateddate, description
FROM (SELECT t.itemID,
             t.note,
             t.color,
             MIN(t.updateddate) OVER (PARTITION BY t.itemId) as MinDate,
             t.description             
      FROM MyTable t) u
where updatedate = MinDate
```

Comment: I couldnt get the window function to work, but the first one works great for what I am doing, thanks DavidG!

I think I need to get my head around using Partition though, not really used it at all. Thanks very much for your answer, I cant however vote it up!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with ROW_NUMBER and PARTITION BY combination, Assuming that your table name is Test, the following could be a select statement that would be providing you the desired output

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(SELECT itemID,
        Note,
        Color,
        UpdatedDate,
        Description,
        RowOrder = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY itemID
                                     ORDER BY updateddate ASC)
 FROM dbo.Test
) AS TempTab
WHERE RowOrder = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Anoo, I need to use PARTITION more, not really used it at all, and dont really have my head around how and when to use it. ill go do a bit of reading ;)